# Character Movement script not moving according to camera rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've taken the movement script from Brackeys' video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc but it isn't working. I took the Character Controller and put it in, I double checked all the code. But the character isn't moving according to rotation of the camera. It only works if I put the camera script in the player host alongside the movement script, but then the capsule object rotates with the camera.

Here is the code for the movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this script attached to? it takes the rotation of the GameObject it is attached to .. not necessarily the Camera rotation if it isn't attached to the camera ...

Comment: @derHugo I attached the script to the main GameObject and took the Character Controller and dragged it in the controller box. I've tried putting both the mouse look script and the movement script in the main GameObject but it makes the player's body move weirdly like it's in creative or something. I wish I could exclude the player body's z and x rotation from the script and keep the y rotation for making the character face left and right. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is your main object? Again: In order to take the camera rotation into account as your title says this script would need to be attached to the `Camera` object since it uses `transform.right` and `transform.forward` .. or alternatively instead of using `transform.right` get a reference to the camera (e.g. `Camera.main`) and instead use `theCamera.transform.right` and `theCamera.transform.forward` ..